# Need help in Parsing Data

Tags: javascript, python, shell, apache-pig

I have this format of data:

```
13 {114800000,117800000}  {114700000} 0.00433424757229875 0.999888367939272 224.821380176483
3 {117800000}  {114700000} 0.00433666704733074 0.999776885319054 224.796313701717
5 {114800000}  {114700000} 0.00444505952876369 0.999564744287269 224.748614537403
6 {114700000}  {114800000} 0.00444505952876369 0.999455989554999 224.748614537403
14 {114700000,117800000}  {114800000} 0.00433424757229875 0.99944208881946 224.745488665843
```

And am looking for results in this format using pig/python/shell scripting.
Can anyone help me with it?

```
13  114800000   117800000   114700000   0.004334248 0.999888368 224.8213802
3   117800000   null        114700000   0.004336667 0.999776885 224.7963137
5   114800000   null        114700000   0.00444506  0.999564744 224.7486145
6   114700000   null        114800000   0.00444506  0.99945599  224.7486145
14  114700000   117800000   114800000   0.004334248 0.999442089 224.7454887
```

Comment: What attempts have you made?

Comment: Please show evidence of the research carried out, the code you have implemented and the exact issue you are experiencing ... please review [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i used this code 

max2 = 0
file.each { line
    fields = line.split(" ")
    fields[2-1] remove "{}"
    subfields = fields[2-1].split(",")
    if length(subfields)>max2: max=length(subfields)
}
#max == number of columns in second field
file.each { line
    fields = line.split(" ")
    fields[2-1] remove "{}"
    subfields = fields[2-1].split(",")
    exsubfields = [ 'null' for x in range(0,max2) ]
    for ndx in length(subfields):
        exsubfields[ndx] = subfields[ndx]
    fields[2-1] = exsubfields
    flatten
    if length(subfields)>max2: max=length(subfields)
}

Comment: Thank you for suggestions will keep that in mind for next time

Comment: Code posted in comments is hard to read. Please edit your question and add all information in the question, formatting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with a simple split. Let's assume you have the information in a file called input.txt

```
import re
fd = open("input.txt", "r")
output = []
for line in fd:
    l = re.findall(r"[\w']+", line)
    if len(line) < 7:
       l.insert(2, "null")
    output.append(l)
```

I'm assuming that there are 7 numbers on each line and when a number is missing is in the third column.

That should work.